# Numpy "double"-broadcasting - is it possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.x, array-broadcasting

Is it possible to use "double"-broadcasting to remove the loop in the following code? In other words, to broadcast across the entire time array `T` as well as the same-dimensioned arrays `freqs` and `phases`.

```
freqs = np.arange(100)
phases = np.random.randn(len(freqs))
T = np.arange(0, 500)

signal = np.zeros(len(T))
for i in xrange(len(signal)):
    signal[i] = np.sum(np.cos(freqs*T[i] + phases))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape `T` as a 2d array by adding a new axis to it, which will trigger the broadcasting when *multiplied/added* with a 1d array, and then later on use `numpy.sum` to collapse this axis:

```
np.sum(np.cos(freqs * T[:,None] + phases), axis=1)
#                      add new axis        remove it with sum
```

---

*Testing*:

```
(np.sum(np.cos(freqs * T[:,None] + phases), axis=1) == signal).all()
# True
```

​

Comment: am I right that this is actually the same as my answer below - broadcasting in this case means constructing the outer product? asking purely for clarity.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. `np.outer(freqs, T)` is the same as `freqs[:,None] * T`.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that just came to me (but which may be computationally expensive?) is to construct the arguments as a matrix:

```
phases = phases.reshape((len(phases), 1))
argumentMatrix = np.outer(freqs, T) + phases
cosineMatrix = np.cos(argumentMatrix)
signal = np.sum(cosineMatrix, axis=0) # sum, collapsing columns
```